# Moment of inertia integration error

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, moment-of-inertia

I am trying to calculate moment of inertia of a curve. I tried two methods both of which should yield the same result, but only the first method provides the correct solution.

I'd appreciate it very much if someone can tell me where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: You are calculating the area moment, not the moment of inertia. Two completely different things.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Where is your axis of rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second integration is wrong. The moment of inertia of a uniform rod with mass $M$ and length $L$ about its end is $\frac{1}{3}ML^2$, not $M\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^2$. This introduces the $\frac{3}{4}$ discrepancy between your two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right: in the second you forgot the Proper Inertia component:
Total Inertia of an area $I_{tot} = I_p + I_t$ where $I_t = A \times y^2$ as you wrote (comes from Parallel Axis theorem), but in this case $I_p$ is not zero as in the first calculation: here $I_p = dx \ h^{3/12}$ by heart (look for Inertia tables online).

If you want to be very sure not to make mistakes, go straight: in $N$ dimensions always make the computation has $N$ integrals. Here it should be double integral of a $dA = dx \ dy \ $.
In this way you don't loose pieces back.

I suggest to study a bit more theory before...

Comment: OMG i cannot believe i was integrating it as a line. thanks you guys for correcting me, i have been lost for a while on this, thank you @dandan0101 and enrico.dila

Comment: no worries, it happens (vote up then :D ) my suggestion: compute carefully when needed. it means asking yourself "does this make sense?" at every step

Comment: you know i used to think, haha its so simple its a simple integration is this even a problem, this was a humbling experience, thanks again